# Launch error on Eclipse using Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, java, launcher, icons, eclipse

Hi could you help me to resolve this error? I'm currently new to ubuntu and I'm trying to run eclipse on my ubuntu.

```
Failed to execute child process "/home/desktop/Documents/eclipse/eclipse" (Permission denied)
```

I have created desktop on eclipse using this code:

```
[Desktop Entry] Name=Eclipse  
Type=Application   
Exec=my eclipse path-  
Terminal=false Icon= my eclipse icon path-  
Comment=Integrated Development Environment  
NoDisplay=false   
Categories=Development;IDE;  
Name[en]=eclipse.desktop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a permissions error. Open Nautilus and navigate to

```
/home/desktop/Documents/eclipse/
```

Then right-click and go to properties. Change the permissions to read, write, and execute. That should work.

Comment: I couldn't see the execute only read & write. hmmm

Comment: @SaulJacobCadungogLabares You could use chmod. Use the man pages or Google to help.